# Activate conda environment in docker and using image in WDL

Tags: docker, conda, wdl

I am developing dockerfile where i need to activate conda environment(working fine)

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /app

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

# Make RUN commands use the new environment:
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]


# The code to run when container is started:
COPY test.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "myenv"]
```

**environment.yml**

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - flask
  - numpy
```

**test.py**

```
import numpy as np
 
# Creating a rank 1 Array
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print("Array with Rank 1: \n",arr)
```

Building and pushing docker image:

```
docker build -t docker.io/myaccount/condaset:latest .
docker push docker.io/myaccount/condaset:latest
```

I tested the docker image which seems to be working fine.

```
docker run docker.io/myaccount/condaset python test.py 
Array with Rank 1: 
 [1 2 3]
```

but when i use the same docker image in WDL it gives error.

****test.wdl****

```
version 1.0
task my_run
{
    input
    {
      String somevar
    }

    parameter_meta {
    }

    command {
       set -exo pipefail
       python /app/test.py 
    }
    
    output { 
       File out = ''
    }
    
    runtime {
       docker: "docker.io/myaccount/condaset:latest"
    }
}
workflow my_wokflow
{
    input
    {
       String somevar
    }

    call my_run
    {
      input: somevar=somevar
    }
}
```

**input.json**

```
{
  "my_wokflow.somevar": "hello_world"
}
```

Error while running WDL:

**java -jar ~/bin/cromwell-58.jar run test.wdl -i input.json**

```
 [First 3000 bytes]:+ python /app/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

It seems conda environment become deactivated before calling dockerimage in WDL. How can i fix such issue?

Answer (score 0):

When cromwell runs a container, it overrides the `ENTRYPOINT` script, so your conda environment does not get activated when the WDL is run.

There are a a couple of different ways you can get the behavior you want.

1. Add your conda environment to the your `PATH` in the Dockerfile:

   ```
   ENV PATH="/opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin:$PATH"
   ```
2. In your WDL, supply an absolute path to `python`:

   ```
   /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/python /app/test.py
   ```

Additionally, in your WDL, the `my_run` output stanza will result in an error. You need to give a non-empty file name for `out`:

```
    command {
       set -exo pipefail
       /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/python /app/test.py  > out.txt
    }   
    
    output { 
       File out = 'out.txt'
    }
```